# "My location" is off by a 100 miles when using Google Maps in different browsers on Windows 10 laptop which has GPS built in

Tags: windows-10, laptop, gps

I have a Dell Latitude E7240. Location services are on in Settings - Location. I have tried accessing Google Maps in Firefox and Edge. Google Maps is not even showing the blue dot and Waze location is off almost 100 miles.

I have been using Betternet VPN a lot for a few days. Can it be the culprit?

Comment: Can you include the model of your laptop?

Comment: @CaldeiraG Dell Latitude E7240

Comment: Please post a screenshot from Device Manager showing the GPS module.

Comment: You, of course, need to be outdoors to use true GPS. To test it, switch off all other connectivity, wifi, ethernet, anything 'telephone' capable such as 4G dongle etc & go outdoors, with a good view of a lot of open sky, not between tall buildings etc..

Comment: @gronostaj The device manager is not showing any GPS device but I do have a "Location" quick settings toggle. And on previous occassions, my laptop has shown me precise locations.

Comment: If no true GPS, then you are reliant on accurate data as to the locations of nearby wifi APs, phone masts etc. If someone nearby has recently moved house, bringing their wifi with them, it could take a few weeks for that position to be updated. You could test by moving 100m or more away from your current location & test again.

Comment: @Tetsujin okay, thanks for explaining. But what about the location detection issue? I used to be able to see my accurate location. Should I include more info?

Comment: I added a bit to my previous comment, refresh the page to see it

Comment: @Tetsujin will try that

Comment: This all may be dependant on where you are. In the countryside, you might only have 1 or 2 APs or phone masts anywhere near you. In a big city you'll probably always be close to 50 or more APs & a massive crossing network of phone 'mini masts'.

Comment: BTW if your device **should** have GPS installed, there's a guide here - https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-uk/sln289815/set-up-use-and-troubleshooting-gps-using-the-dell-location-and-gps-utility?lang=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to Google] [1](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/2839911?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en&oco=1), on a 'Computer', as opposed to Android or iOS,

> Maps estimates where you are from sources like your web browser’s location information.

This means that as of today, Maps won't use your GPS.
If near to you the WiFi locations haven't been collected by the Google cars when they took pictures for street view (a practice which in Europe is not allowed for privacy reasons), Google will use your IP address, or rather the location where your ISP has registered that IP address to be.
Google could maybe also cross-track you through your cell phone use, but this will still be inaccurate.

You might be able to improve if you head to google.com, make some search, scroll to the bottom and click on "Use exact position". Like that, google will get all the information your browser has available. But I doubt this will include GPS. [As Mozilla puts it] [2](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/does-firefox-share-my-location-websites):

> Firefox gathers information about nearby wireless access points and your computer’s IP address and sends it to the default geolocation service provider, Google Location Services, to get an estimate of your location

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It was really helpful. BTW do you know any any web apps/Windows apps that use GPS? Thanks! :)

Comment: @DivyanshAdwani you might try to install some Android Virtual Machine, and use the Android apps on your PC - so you could install the Android Google Maps. But I don't know if they can make use of your GPS location